# Pass id from Vue router param to component's Vuex dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuex-modules

I have backend Laravel API where i get

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Toni Stoyanov",
"email": "toni.nikolaev.23@gmail.com"
},

"id": 2,
"name": "Thomas Shelby",
"email": "st3851ba@gmail.com"
}
]
```

In my routes in Vue :

```
 {
  path: '/users/:id',
  component: UserDetails,
  props:true
},
```

I want to Display every single user for example with users/1 i want to get my first record from API.

In Vuex state i have :

```
namespaced: true,
    state(){
        return{
            users: {
              
            }
        }
    },
```

getters:

```
getUsers(state){
        return state.users
    }
```

mutations:

```
SET_USER(state, data){
        state.users = data
    }
```

and this action where i fetch all users:

```
async setUsers(context){
        let response = await axios.get('users/all')

        context.commit('SET_USER',response.data)
    }
```

In my DisplayUser.vue i have :

```
props:['id'],
    data(){
        return{
            selectedUser: null
        }
    },
    created(){
       this.$store.dispatch('users/setUsers')

        this.selectedUser = this.$store.getters['users/getUsers'].find(user => user.id === this.id);
    },
```

First i dispatch my action to get data from API and after that in selectedUsers try to find the same id user..but in console i get

```
this.$store.getters['users/getUsers'].find is not a function.
```

If i set in users static data everything works sometimes! But when i fetch them from API no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the getter before the http request has completed.  It should be enough to wait for the promise in `created`.

**The prop is a string**

Also, the prop is coming as a string, so a `===` will not match.  You can cast it to a `Number(this.id)` first:

**Using `.then` syntax:**

```js
created(){
  this.$store.dispatch('users/setUsers').then(res => {
    this.selectedUser = this.$store.getters['users/getUsers'].find(user => user.id === Number(this.id));
  });
}
```

**Or using `async/await` syntax:**

```js
async created(){   // async keyword
  await this.$store.dispatch('users/setUsers')   // await this
  this.selectedUser = this.$store.getters['users/getUsers'].find(user => user.id === Number(this.id));
}
```